# Having a unrecognized selector sent to instance based on a button selected state

Tags: ios, button, swift, selector

I have a button in a UIControllerView set to follow a particular user with the Parse.com backend.

I want this behavior :

-> user is not a friend, button state = unselected, perform following action in Parse.com => change button state to selected

-> user is a friend, button state = selected, perform unfollowing action in parse.com => change button state to unselected

My problem is :

if the button is selected (because user is already a friend) = > everything work good

if the button IS NOT selected (because user is not a friend) =>

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Sliked.FriendsProfileViewControler followButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance    0x7f7f7ad63370'
  *** First throw call stack:
 (
   0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aabe3f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c5ecbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
   2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aac550d -[NSObject(NSObject)    doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa1d7fc ___forwarding___ + 988
   4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aa1d398 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
   5   UIKit                               0x000000010b3499ee -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
   6   UIKit                               0x000000010b44fbd0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
   7   UIKit                               0x000000010b44ef9f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
   8   UIKit                               0x000000010b38f3b8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
   9   UIKit                               0x000000010b38fce3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
  10  UIKit                               0x000000010b35cae1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
  11  UIKit                               0x000000010b369bad _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
  12  UIKit                               0x000000010b345233 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
  13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9f3ad1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
  14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9e999d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
  15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9e8fd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
  16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a9e8a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
  17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010db299f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
  18  UIKit                               0x000000010b348550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
  19  Sliked                              0x0000000109273a4e top_level_code + 78
  20  Sliked                              0x0000000109273a8a main + 42
  21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cdc6145 start + 1
   )
   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My code look like this :

```
    @IBOutlet var followUnfollowButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func followUnfollow (sender: AnyObject) {



    let user:PFObject = userPassed
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    let relation : PFRelation = currentUser.relationForKey("KfriendsRelation")

    if  !followUnfollowButton.selected {

        followUnfollowButton.selected = true

        followUnfollowButton.setTitle("Unfollow", forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        followUnfollowButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 117/255, green: 201/255, blue: 223/255, alpha: 1.0)

        relation.addObject(user)

        PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeed:Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("not working")
            }



            println("following user succes")

        }

    }

    else  {


        followUnfollowButton.selected = false
        followUnfollowButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 255/255, blue: 9/255, alpha: 1.0)


        relation.removeObject(user)

        PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock{   (succeed:Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println(error)
                println("can't unfollow user")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I tried to remove the Parse logical, just to test if the changes to the selected state are working good when i push the button but have the same error.

This is very strange, what did i miss ?

Comment: "sent to instance..." What does it say next. That's pretty much the most important part of the error message that you cut off.

Comment: Somewhere you are calling the function `followButton:` but you don't seem to have that anywhere in your code. I'd recommend doing a project search for "followButton"

Comment: You're enabling some sort of event handler and specifying `followButton:` as the method to handle the event.  But it's being "sent" to a view controller, not the intended object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this error means is that the method name (called a 'Selector') cannot be found. Literally the object that is listening for the tap event doesn't have the appropriately named method that it should have ("followButton:").

Swift is a dynamic language so methods can be created at runtime. So you need to pass it the name of the method ('Selector') it expects.

In this case, your tap event listener is expecting  a method called "followButton:"

Check where you assign the button listener, it will look something like this:

```
_tapRecoginizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"tap:")
```

For your case, you are looking for where the action says "followButton:". Make sure the target has that method and the appropriate listener (in your case likely a UITapGesture)

Keep in mind "followButton:" is different than "followButton". The ":" means the method is expecting an object to be passed as an argument so make sure you don't forget the ":"

Also keep in mind:
If you are using the interface builder, check that you left in legacy code when renaming. If connected an IBAction, then deleted it from code, open the object up in the Interface Builder, click the right most (arrow) tab, and delete the touch up inside action.

Deleting from code doesn't update the object in the interface builder so make sure you delete its touch up inside event listener too!

It sounds like you connected an IBAction and renamed it, and now its looking for a method that's not in the script. So follow these steps to fix it. Delete the reference in the interface builder, reconnect it (control drag), and name it again.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a UITapGestureRecognizer, i just have an IBAction set up with my story board with the control drag method.

Comment: Can I see your IBAction called "followButton:". I dont see it

Comment: It's something i removed, i can't find it in the Connection inspector. What should i do ?

Comment: It looks like what I said earlier, the script listening for the followButton: doesnt have that method to implement.

Comment: I updated my answer, and you confirmed my suspicion. If my answer is unclear let me know otherwise follow those steps and you can fix it easily.

Comment: I can't find it, tried to delete my new one and re create one but still the same issue. Also, why is it working when the button is selected ?

Comment: You didn't delete it.Check every object for the listener.

Comment: Also, just add a method followButton: (with a UIGestureRecognizer) to your code and put a println() statement. I bet you it will fire!